# C++ inline assembly PROC ENDP error

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I am trying to create procedure in assembly x86 inside a C++ program. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

   _asm{

  input1 PROC
            push inputnumber
            lea eax, inputmsg
            push eax
            call printf
            add esp, 8


            push ebx
            lea eax, format
            push eax
            call scanf
            add esp, 8  

            jmp check1
            ret
        input1 ENDP
}
}
```

However, when I try to compile the program with Visual studio I get the following error:

```
C2400 inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'PROC'
C2400 inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'ENDP'
```

I've read online but I cannot resolve it. Any suggestions how to fix it ?

Comment: It's not fixable, you can't declare asm procedure in C++ procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised that those are the only errors you get.  PROC and ENDP are not recognized by the C inline assembler.  Anyway, defining a function inside a function in C isn't a good idea.  Try

```
int main(){
   _asm{
        push inputnumber
        lea eax, inputmsg
        :
        call scanf
        add esp, 8  

        ret
    }
}
```

You will then end up with a whole bunch of undeclared variables and possibly warnings about scanf if you're using one of the MS compilers.